# SerialInitContextFactory not found in glassfish naming

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, jndi

This one starts to drive me completely nuts ...

I want to create a Glassfish client application using Maven.

For that, I've added the requried gf-client dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.appclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>gf-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then, wanting to contact my Glassfish server, running on the same application, I do the usual lookup :

```
Properties p = new Properties();
// optional. Defaults to localhost. Only needed if web server is running
// on a different host than the appserver
p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
// optional. Defaults to 3700. Only needed if target orb port is not
// 3700.
p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
Context context = new InitialContext(p);
// Stores the list of reachable EJBs
return context.lookup(interfacesToNames.getProperty(className));
```

Unfortunatly, when doing so, all I get is

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/enterprise/naming/impl/SerialInitContextFactory]
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/enterprise/naming/impl/SerialInitContextFactory
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:63)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:671)
        ... 9 more
```

After some checks, I've noticed that my `glassfish-naming-3.1.jar` is present in CLASSPATH for that client application. And, according to Eclipse code lookup, it is this jar that should contain `com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory`. However, if in debug mode, I do `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/sun/enterprise/naming/impl/SerialInitContextFactory")` it returns me null, which clearly indicates that the class can't be found.

For more infos, the JAR is copied from my local maven repository using this plugin configuration :

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package output directory</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <prependGroupId>true</prependGroupId>
                        <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                        <outputDirectory>${dependencies.outputDir}/jars</outputDirectory>
                        <prefix>${dependencies.outputDir}</prefix>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Furthermore, I have to confess that, when running a simple test using the same API to connect to Glassfish server, there is absolutely no problem, which directs me to a ClassLoader issue.

When running that client, the current class loader is (as denoted by `getClass().getClassLoader().getClass().getName()`) `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`. Which unfortunatly is exactly the same than when running unit test.

So, what can I do to solve that bug ?

**EDIT** Class exists in `glassfish-naming-3.1.jar`, but does not seems to be findable by standard classloader.

**EDIT** An interesting discovery :

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/sun/enterprise/naming/impl") = jar:file:/C:/Users/pouet/pouet/target/jars/glassfish-naming-3.1.jar!/com/sun/enterprise/naming/impl
```

while

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/sun/enterprise/naming/impl/SerialInitContextFactory") = null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a reason I not totally understand, there is a configured Context classloader when run in application. This classloader seems to use some kind of OSGi naming restriction.

As a consequence, to avoid the bug, I reset the context class loader :

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
```

And it worked !

Comment: Please file a bug with the project.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the ACC? Your solution seems contrived.

Comment: @Alexis_MP well, in fact, we also discussed this question on the strasbg ML :-) Anyway, this application is started as plugin code by InDesign, and maybe this alter some behaviours (but I unfortunatly have no time to find a better solution now).

Comment: how is the ACC invoked?