# Maven dependencies for glassfish stand-alone client

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

I have to test ejb's deployed on a glassfish 3.1.2.2 running on a separated machine.

My client is like that

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost","x.x.x.x");
p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort","3700");
Context context = new InitialContext(p);
Test service = (Test) context.lookup("java:global/base-ejb-1.0/TestImpl");
```

If I download and extract glassfish on my pc I can add

```
glassfish-client-module.jar
```

to my build path and it's working fine.

But how can I do if I don't have glassfish on my pc.

Impossible to find a maven dependency with the right libraries.  Always something missing or exception.

Comment: Not certain but is this the dependency you are looking for?
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.glassfish.main.appclient.client|gf-client-module|3.1.2.2|hk2-jar

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Missing artifact org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:jar:2.3.2
- Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6.0

Comment: Please refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002948/how-to-setup-jndi-for-glassfish-3-1-2-for-a-stand-alone-client/19055514#19055514

Comment: Ok, thanks, but it's using the glassfish installed on the pc.  It's seems it is not possible to find a repository with the good dependency to work without any glassfish installed.