# Glassfish NameNotFoundException for remote JNDI lookup

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jndi

**clarification**:

all three names (I think, will confirm) work when everything is on localhost -- one JVM.  None work when the client and Glassfish are on seperate computers.

The answer might very well be correct, it might be a different problem entirely.

---

What is the correct name to and syntax to lookup `MyQueueRemote`?  When the client does a `JNDI` lookup on localhost, it runs fine.  When the same client does a `JNDI` lookup on a remote server, a `NameNotFoundException` is thrown client by the client.

[The SingletonQueue deploys and runs, locally, correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029729/singleton-queue-with-jpa).  However, while the `EAR` deploys remotely (see below), the client cannot correctly lookup and resolve the remote lookup, throwing `Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: dur.bounceme.net.remote.MyQueueRemote not found`.

the client runs correctly against `SingletonQueue` when deployed to Glassfish as an `EAR`:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/appclient -client NetBeansProjects/SingletonClient/dist/SingletonClient.jar 
Sep 24, 2014 10:44:00 PM net.bounceme.dur.jndi.RemoteJNDI main
INFO: 
Sep 24, 2014 10:44:00 PM net.bounceme.dur.jndi.RemoteJNDI main
INFO: {org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl}
Sep 24, 2014 10:44:05 PM net.bounceme.dur.jndi.RemoteJNDI main
INFO: id    379
Sep 24, 2014 10:44:05 PM net.bounceme.dur.jndi.RemoteJNDI main
INFO: id    380
Sep 24, 2014 10:44:05 PM net.bounceme.dur.jndi.RemoteJNDI main
INFO: id    381
Sep 24, 2014 10:44:05 PM net.bounceme.dur.jndi.RemoteJNDI main
```

the remote Glassfish logs showing the `JNDI` name for `MyQueueRemote`:

```
ejb@ix:~$ 
ejb@ix:~$ tail glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log  -n 63
[2014-09-25T01:50:10.470-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [jts.startup_msg] [javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.CosTransactions] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1411624177172] [timeMillis: 1411624210470] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [3700]]]

[2014-09-25T01:50:20.028-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00054] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1411624177172] [timeMillis: 1411624220028] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Portable JNDI names for EJB MyQueue: [java:global/SingletonQueue/SingletonQueue-ejb/MyQueue, java:global/SingletonQueue/SingletonQueue-ejb/MyQueue!dur.bounceme.net.remote.MyQueueRemote]]]

[2014-09-25T01:50:20.030-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00055] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1411624177172] [timeMillis: 1411624220030] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB MyQueue: [dur.bounceme.net.remote.MyQueueRemote#dur.bounceme.net.remote.MyQueueRemote, dur.bounceme.net.remote.MyQueueRemote]]]
```

the client stacktrace when run against the remote Glassfish server:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/appclient -client NetBeansProjects/SingletonClient/dist/SingletonClient.jar 
Sep 24, 2014 10:58:47 PM net.bounceme.dur.jndi.RemoteJNDI main
INFO: 
Sep 24, 2014 10:58:47 PM net.bounceme.dur.jndi.RemoteJNDI main
INFO: {org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=ix.bounceme.net, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl}
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'dur.bounceme.net.remote.MyQueueRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=ix.bounceme.net, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: dur.bounceme.net.remote.MyQueueRemote not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at net.bounceme.dur.jndi.RemoteJNDI.main(RemoteJNDI.java:16)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: dur.bounceme.net.remote.MyQueueRemote not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor92.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:173)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
thufir@dur:~$
```

client code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.jndi;

import dur.bounceme.net.remote.MyQueueRemote;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class RemoteJNDI {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RemoteJNDI.class.getName());

    public static void main(String... args) throws NamingException {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        log.info(ctx.getNameInNamespace());
        log.info(ctx.getEnvironment().toString());
        Object obj = ctx.lookup("dur.bounceme.net.remote.MyQueueRemote");
        MyQueueRemote queue = (MyQueueRemote) obj;
        while (true) {
            log.info("id\t" + queue.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/19055514/262852

Comment: see also https://blogs.oracle.com/MaheshKannan/entry/portable_global_jndi_names

Answer (score 1):

```
Portable JNDI names for EJB MyQueue: [java:global/SingletonQueue/SingletonQueue-ejb/MyQueue, java:global/SingletonQueue/SingletonQueue-ejb/MyQueue!dur.bounceme.net.remote.MyQueueRemote]

java:global/SingletonQueue/SingletonQueue-ejb/MyQueue
java:global/SingletonQueue/SingletonQueue-ejb/MyQueue!dur.bounceme.net.remote.MyQueueRemote
```

Try one of theese two instead of

```
dur.bounceme.net.remote.MyQueueRemote
```

Comment: **both** of those `java:global/...` work fine **locally**.  None work remotely, same `NameNotFoundException`.

Comment: What do you mean "remotely"?
Both JVMs client and server running on different hosts? If so, perhaps you are running glassfish on local host same time. And how do you configure your initial context? Where do you pass params so it connects to remote glassfish naming service?

Comment: the params are passed from `jndi.properties`, this is what the default constructor for the initial context pulls them from.  `localhost` works fine, but the remote address fails as above.

Comment: So, you cannot connect to remote naming service.If you are running linux on remote server, maybe because of iptables blocking access?

Comment: the error is `NameNotFound`, and, also, ssh works fine.  Assuming your correct, how do you establish that iptables are blocking access?  with a ping?  or, how is that **disproved**?  I don't believe it's a firewall, FWIW -- but how is that established.  larger scope question now.  I go back to the specific error message, `NameNotFound` -- why isn't it found?

Comment: Sorry. I am understand now, you have NameNotFound for remote glassfish. So you can connect. Can you see that JNDI name in glassfish admin web console?

Usually on port 4848 "Server"->"Resources"

Comment: @BOWSER I asked a better question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322294/corba-lookup-for-javacomp-env-or-javaglobal   I'm not sure whether to accept your answer on this question or not.  Also, I put my code on github for reference, because it spans several applications.  Even if you don't have time to look at the newer question, I appreciate your help.